# Run all iterations in postman and then a call a specific API in a collection

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I have a Rest API which is used for registering some data using POST request. In postman i have multiple data iterations that i run it for and all that data is updated successfully and validated. The id generated is dynamic and is saved in postman test script for each iteration using the

> "pm.info.iteration"

for each id for later use

[

```
[
 {
    "name":"abcd",
    "address":"asd 123 xyz"
    "id": 123456
 },
 {
    "name":"xyz",
    "address":"asd 123 xyz"
    "id": 987123
 }
]
```

Now i have another API which retrieves the whole list using a GET request.The validation scenario is to call the GET API once all the itearations are complete and validate the count and data. Is there a way to iterate on the data for POST request, after completion , call the GET request and check the count?
How to achieve this when running with multiple folders and multiple tests inside each folder with dynamic data?